# How to display everything using gridview table unless user selects dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, stored-procedures

#### Hi I have a stored procedure from where I am selecting columns for my table

```
@ID nvarchar(200)

AS

BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SELECT 
      [ID]
      ,[Subject]
      ,[From]
      ,[To]
      ,[Body]
      ,[Comment] From Status 
      where ID=@ID 
  
END
```

I have only one read only gridview table and a dropdown list with 2 options accepted,deny.I want page to load all the emails in the database first and then when user selects ID accepted or denied to show that column emails. My problem is if all the emails are displayed in gridview when user selects options it's not working or vice versa if options are working then all the emails are not diplayed when page loads. So I want everything to be displayed first unless user selects option.

Answer (score 1):

Change your proc to this

```
@ID nvarchar(200)

AS

BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON
SELECT 
  [ID]
  ,[Subject]
  ,[From]
  ,[To]
  ,[Body]
  ,[Comment] From Status 
  where (ID=@ID  or @ID="All")
END
```

And then add another first element to the dropdown list as so:

```
<asp:listitem Value="All" Text="All" />
```

Now, when the page loads, the ID passed will be `All`, and everything will be returned; unless the user selectes `Accepted`, or `Denied`.

Comment: good. for me the OP's question is not clear but after seeing your answer i understand OP's question.